# Apply a function to every combination of components in a list

Tags: list, function, matrix, datatable, apply

I have a survey dataset that look something like below table(randomly generated).
Each customer does multiple rating for multiple products.
Each customer rates all four products. There are 3 types of ratings.

| Cust_id | product | rating1 | rating2 | rating3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 | 3 | 7 |
| 2 | B | 3 | 7 | 2 |
| 3 | A | 9 | 5 | 8 |
| 1 | C | 4 | 5 | 7 |
| 4 | A | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 4 | B | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 5 | D | 9 | 4 | 1 |

I would like to calculate the average score for each rating for each product. My desire outcome looks like below.

| product | avg_rating1 | avg_rating2 | avg_rating3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 3 | 6 |
| B | 6 | 7 | 3 |
| C | 2 | 5 | 8 |
| D | 8 | 9 | 7 |

I have created a list that stores all kinds of product and rating types. I have also createD a function to calculate the average score. I couldn't figure out how to apply my function to every combination of the elements in my input list.

My input list

```
input <- list(Product = c('A',"B","C","D"), rating =c('rating1','rating2','rating3'))
```

My function

```
avg.rate <- function(input, dat){
  require(data.table)
  setDT(dat)
  dat$Product %in% input$Product
  dat[,mean(get(input$rating), na.rm = TRUE)]
}
```

I'm not sure how to apply my avg.rate function to the list I generated. My goal is to produce a matrix of averages scores for each product and rating type.

Comment: Your question is about [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)?

Comment: Yes. I'd like a solution using R.